# geoNear() is not working as expected when using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongodb and mongoose as ODM for my app. I have a document holding a location for a restaurant. The model (schema) is look like this:

```
var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type:String, required:true},
    address: String,
    coords: {type:[Number], index:'2dsphere', required:true},
});
```

and here is my sample data:

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("56b39d9673ff055a098dee71"),
    "name" : "Holycow STEAKHOUSE",
    "address" : "somewhere",
    "coords" : [
        106.7999044,
        -6.2916982
    ]
```

Then I use mongoose to get the restaurant location from somewhere within approximately 2 Km from the restaurant. I read from mongodb doc that we have to supply maxDistance param in radiance and distanceMultiplier with earth radius, so i put this following code into my controller:

```
var point = {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [106.8047355, -6.2875187] // the test data, approximately 2 km from the restaurant
    }

    var geoOptions = {
        spherical: true,
        num: 10,
        maxDistance: 5 / 6371 , // i set maximum distance to 5 km. to make sure I found the place.
        distanceMultiplier: 6371
    }

Loc.geoNear(point, geoOptions, function(err, results, stats){
            var locations = [];
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                sendJsonResponse(res, 404, err);
            } else {
                results.forEach(function(doc){
                    locations.push({
                       distance: doc.dis,
                       name: doc.obj.name,
                       address: doc.obj.address,
                       _id: doc.obj._id
                   });
               });
               sendJsonResponse(res, 200, locations);     
            } 
        });
```

but it failed to find the restaurant. I have read the docs for two hours, but still have no clue. what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var geoOptions = {
    spherical: true,
    num: 10,
    maxDistance: 5 * 1000 , // Convert kilometers to meters
}
```

I think we are reading the same book. Your code is familiar, and
I also encountered the same problem.

Your code is not working properly because you assume that `maxDistace` is using the unit radians. But no, `naxDistance` is using meters. You need also to remove `distanceMultiplier` because it will convert your `maxDistance` to radians, which is not the right unit.

Try this link: [MongoDB Docs $maxDistance](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/maxDistance/)

Comment: Same book, and this helped me out. Thanks.